# Rails gem with javascript dependency

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sprockets

I'm writing a rails gem which requires angular, so I added it to my gem's dependencies:

`s.add_dependency "angularjs-rails", "~> 1.6.2"`

Now, how should I include angular ? I tried to add it directly in my gem's main js script but sprockets fails with this kind of error:

```
couldn't find file 'angular' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths:
  ...
  /Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/grid_builder-rails-be353dff709f/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/grid_builder-rails-be353dff709f/app/assets/stylesheets
  ...
```

When I try to include angular in an application that uses my gem, before including my gem's script, the error is quite the same...

So should I just specify that my gem requires angularjs-rails to be added in the app Gemfile, or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: You need to `require 'angularjs-rails'` in your gem's module file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Richard Peck proposed, I required `angularjs-rails` in my gem's module file, and everything went fine:

```
require 'angularjs-rails'

module GridBuilder
  module Rails
    require 'grid_builder/rails/engine'
    require 'grid_builder/rails/version'
    require 'grid_builder/rails/helper'
  end
end
```

And in my gem's js script:

```
//= require angular
```

Thank you :)